# Find path from A to B which length ≈ L

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, depth-first-search

I have an undirected weighted graph.

I want to find the path from A to B which length is as close as possible to a specific value "L".

To do that, I have been doing a DFS to check all the possible paths... When L is relatively small, it's ok. But when I ask for a bigger L, it takes too much time to complete. I added some criteria to stop searching useless paths but that cannot solve the problem.

So I was wondering how to do what I am searching for. Is DFS the only solution ? I thought about genetic algorithms but I don't know if it would work.

Thank you !

Comment: Looks like a topic for https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ok, I will check there then thanks

Comment: This is generally a hard problem (like [longest path](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem)).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there any way to find an approximate solution ?

Comment: A simple approximation that I can think of is to perform a Dijkstra from start and end and memorize at each node (X) how far from the start (A) and how far from the destination (B) it is. Then scan over all nodes and check which one has the closest sum of these values to L. This way you will find the "shortest path via some intermediate node (X) that has length closest to L".

Comment: That seems like a great idea ! But actually I am trying to find a cycle, that means A node and B node are the same. So obviously I will get the same result... The path will not look as a cycle :/

Comment: To find cycles you may want to use breadth first search (bfs). 
Using bfs on unweighted (or equally weighted) graph grantees that then the first time a node is visited (in your case, where A and B are the same,  at start) is the shortest path to that node. 
If you visit it for the second time - you have a cycle with a known length. You need to add a stop criteria based on the length.

Comment: The problem is that BFS takes too much time in very large graphs.  So I am searching for an alternative, using Dijkstra from 2 nodes and finding a sum seems great